# Downloading multiple urls with aiohttp Python 3

Tags: python, web-scraping, asynchronous

I am trying to use aiohttp library in python to download information from url. I have about 300 000 urls. They are saved in file "my_file.txt". When I get web page, I extract pairs of a question and an answer from ask.fm. (it is a website where you can post an anonymous question to some user, and get an answer). And then I look for the next page of answers from the current user, and add it to the list new_urls to use it in the next iteration of a program.

The problem is: the speed of my program is about 1000 pages/minute. Can I somehow speed it up? Do I do something wrong?
If I change number of TCPConnections -- nothing changes.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import time

new_urls = []

k = [0]

async def fetch_url(session, url):
    async with session.get(url, timeout=1000 * 60) as response:
        f = await response.text()
        quest_answ_user = []
        try:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
            s = soup.find_all('article', attrs={'class': 'item streamItem streamItem-answer '})
            for el in s:
                quest = el.find('header').find('h2').text
                list_ans = el.find_all('div', attrs={'class': ['streamItem_content']})
                if len(list_ans) == 0:
                    continue
                ans = list_ans[0].text
                quest_answ_user.append([quest, ans])
            next_page = soup.select('.item-page-next')
            if len(next_page) != 0:
                new_urls.append(next_page[0].get('href'))
            print(url, len(quest_answ_user))
            k[0] += 1
            print(k)
        except Exception as e:
            print(url)
            print(e)
        return quest_answ_user


async def fetch_all_urls(session, urls):
    results = await asyncio.gather(*[fetch_url(session, url) for url in urls], return_exceptions=True)
    return results


async def get_htmls(urls, loop):
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=100)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop, connector=connector) as session:
        list_dialogue = await fetch_all_urls(session, urls)
    return list_dialogue


def main():
    with open('./my_file.txt', 'r') as f:
        urls = f.readlines()

    cur_t = time.time()
    count = 0

    while len(urls) >= 100 and count <= 50000000:
        urls = ['https://ask.fm' + url.strip('\n') for url in urls]
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        r = loop.run_until_complete(get_htmls(urls, loop))
        mode = 'w' if count == 0 else 'a'
        with open('./dialogues4.txt', mode=mode, encoding='utf-8') as f:
            for item in r:
                try:
                    count += len(item)
                    for i in item:
                        f.write(f'{i}\n')
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)

        print(len(new_urls))
        urls = new_urls.copy()
        new_urls.clear()
        with open('./for_continuation2.txt', 'w') as f:
            for item in urls:
                f.write(f'{item}\n')

    print(count)
    print(time.time() - cur_t)

main()
```